# Random Number Generator for c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write some code in c++ for a game, and I need to use a random number generator.
I want the computer to pick a number between 1 and 713, but it always picks 41.

```
int x;
x = wordbank.size();
int m;
m = rand() % x;
```

Here is my code. wordbank is a vector, and x is the size of wordbank(713). Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: could it be the computers memory saving m? I have no idea honestly

Comment: Read the linked duplicates. They explain exactly why `rand()` always returns the same value for you.

Comment: Don't use `rand() % N` for random numbers. It's horrible. Use `std::mt19937` as shown in the answers this was marked a duplicate of. Also, I recommend watching this 30min talk by Lavavej: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY